# PHP Image/File Sharing Script

Tags: php, html, upload

Does anyone know of any tutorials which take you though a step by step process on making a filesharing script I found lots of how to make file uploaders but none of them return a link for other people to download the stuff uploaded.

be great if someone could hit me back with some sort of tutorial for this

thank

Comment: once you upload the file, you can link to wherever you put it on your server... just like you include an image on an HTML page.. you just have to know the path.

Answer (score 0):

Literally all you need is a hyperlink

```
<?php

   //where
   $url = "http://www.theurlineed.com";
   $myuploadfolder = "/var/www/html/mydir/uploaddir";
   if (is_dir($myuploadfolder)) foreach (scandir($myuploadfolder) as $file){
       if ($file!="." || $file!=".."){
            echo "<p><a href=\"".$url."/".$file."\">".$file."</a></p>\n";
       }       
   }

?>
```

Almost certainly the issue is actually understanding for yourself the `$url` and the `$myuploadfolder` bit at the top. i.e. how to get from "serverland" to "url-land" and no-one can do that for you you have to suck it and see what works.